# Proving Limit of sequence using Epsilon-N definition

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

In class today we were given the sequence $a_n=\frac{5n^2+4}{3n^2+n+1}$ and we had to use the epsilon-N definition to prove that it converges to the limit $\frac{5}{3}$

So far I have done as follows

$|\frac{5n^2+4}{3n^2+n+1}-\frac{5}{3}| <\epsilon$

$|\frac{-5n+7}{3(3n^2+n+1)}| < \epsilon$

$\frac{5n^2+7}{9n^2+3n+3} < \epsilon$

$\frac{5n^2+7}{9n^2+3n+3} < \frac{5n^2+7}{9n^2} < \epsilon$

after this i get stuck because I dont know how to simplify this any further. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear why you go from $-5n+7$ to $5n^2+7$.

For $n>1$, $|-5n+7|=5n-7$, so you have to guarantee
$$
\frac{5n-7}{3n^2+n+1}<3\varepsilon
$$
Note that $5n-7<5n$ and $3n^2+n+1>3n^2$, so
$$
\frac{5n-7}{3n^2+n+1}<\frac{5n}{3n^2}=\frac{5}{3n}
$$
which is less than $3\varepsilon$ as soon as
$$
n>\frac{5}{9\varepsilon}
$$